# Can you explain how int values are stored in bitfields in C, please?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct marks{
    int p:4;
    int c:3;
    unsigned int m:2;
};

void main()
{
    struct marks s = {-15, 5, 3};
    printf("%d %d %d\n", s.p, s.c, s.m);
}
```

Output:

```
1 -3 3
```

Why is the first value printed as 1 and the second value is printed as -3?

Comment: Eh? What range of signed int do you think will fit into 4 bits?  I've never seen anyone use negative ints with bitfields before.

Comment: @MartinJames Well, it could work with one extra bit...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah.  All my embedded jobs are a bit short.

Comment: @MartinJames Mine is a bit too long (shh! I hope my boss isn't here..)

Comment: Ironically, the wikipedia page for [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) has the answer for this exact question in a nice little table.

Comment: A 4-bit signed int represents values -8 to 7. A 3-bit signed int -4 to 3. Your initializers are out of range.

Comment: And how would this very basic question be related to embedded systems?

Comment: @Olaf i think you mean "how would this question not be related to non-embedded systems". surely a basic question applies to all systems

Comment: @Olaf - bitfields tend to be used more on RAM-restricted systems where an array of booleans, (bytes), is inappropriate.  Also, many embedded controllers tend to use bitmasks in union/struct for protocol handling.

Comment: @SteveCox: On embedded systems, C bitfields are very rarely used, as the standard does not even guarantee a specific layout, a compiler might use more complicated operations to modify fields, sign-extension often requires many instructions. And for hardware registers, it is even worse to guarantee a single access. So, no, it is likely **not** used for embedded systems.

Comment: @MartinJames: Nope, often the better way on such systems is to use bit-operations. Only with the Cortex-M3/4 bitfield instructions, they might become more popular. But they still have to be seen very critical for `volatile` types. And for very restricted systems, an implementation is free to implement `_Bool` as single bits.

Comment: Well, if I unionise a set of bitfields totalling 32 bits over an unsigned int, it has worked fine on every compiler I've used.  A set of bitfields is far clearer that a pile of bit ops and the structs can be used as documentation of the protocol units.  Empirically, bitfield unions are  just not a problem as long as you understand them and their limitations.

Answer (score 5):

For `p`, you are allocating 4 bits. Therefore your valid range of values for `p` is 1000B - 0111B or -8 to 7. The fewest number of bits needed for -15 is 5 which in binary would be 10001B. Since you only allocated 4 bits, the sign bit is lost and you are left with 1.

For `c`, your are allocating 3 bits which has a valid range of 100B - 011B or -4 to 3. Since 5 is 101B and outside the valid range, it is displayed as -3.

Comment: thank you for your ans. what basis outside valid range is assigned

Comment: Assuming 2s complement. For sign/maginitude, it would be `-7..7`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The value 5 in binary is 101.  Because the field in question is a 3 bit signed, and the most significant bit is set, the value is negative.  In two's complement representation, it is -3.